# Angular 7: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substr')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I have and angular 7.1.4 app that compiles successfully but when I open the console in my browser I see this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substr')           core.js:14597 
at TruncatePipe.push../src/app/_services/truncate.ts.TruncatePipe.transform (truncate.ts:11:21)
```

If I understand this properly there is something wrong with the bellow code in my truncate.ts file. Here is my code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'truncate'
})
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, limit = 25, completeWords = false, ellipsis = '...') {
    if (completeWords) {
      limit = value.substr(0, limit).lastIndexOf(' ');
    }
    return `${value.substr(0, limit)}${ellipsis}`;
  }
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong here? Any thoughts what could be wrong?

Comment: Try `value?.substr` instead of `value.substr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indraraj26 is pointing out that you should wrap your code in a check-value before executing.

If value is ever null, you cannot take a substring of it, so in order to avoid this scenario, you should check if value != null or "". You can do that simply in Angular by using

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'truncate'
})
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, limit = 25, completeWords = false, ellipsis = '...') {
    if(value){
       if (completeWords) {
          limit = value.substr(0, limit).lastIndexOf(' ');
       }
       return `${value.substr(0, limit)}${ellipsis}`;
    }
  }
}
```

The if-statement will be false for null, and prevent your code from running and thus failing.

Answer (score 2):

above all add one condition

```
if(value){
....your code
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by above all... could you provide an example please :)

Answer (score 1):

Before using `value` you should check if its `undefined` look at the following example:

function:

```js
public validateText(text: string) {
  return text;
}
```

Calling this function now will cause error:

```js
const text = 'just an example' as string | undefined; 

validateText(text);
```

error:

```
TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

In your case you should check value before calling the function or inside it before `substr` or be more specific like so:

```js
if (typeof value === 'string') {
//Your code 
}

// OR in short 

if (value) {
//Your code 
}
```